# Apache cannot fork: cannot allocate memory

Tags: process, perl, apache-httpd, fork

I am running `apache` on Fedora with `mod_perl`. The server forks a process to send an email frequently - and the fork exits.

Suddenly, I got: `Cannot fork: Cannot allocate memory`.  There was plenty of free memory (I did not look too closely, but there was more memory free than in use), not too many `apache` processes running - 10?, low cpu usage, close to 0.  Restarting the server httpd graceful resolved the issue.

What would cause something like this? Is it possible that I got into some kind of a state where the problem was allocating too many processes in the system - and with dropping load failed to recover?

Unfortunately I do not have too much info as I was panicking and trying to get the site up instead of running diagnostics.  :-) So my question is very general: is there anything that's not obvious that would create this behavior when too many processes are allocated?  Anything specific to forking from within apache?  etc

Thank you!

Comment: can you be more precise about this ? how much is "plenty of free memory" ? how much is "not too many processes running" ? Did you run an `htop`-like tool to see what consumes most of the memory ?

Comment: Yes, can you be also generous in sharing your apache config (mostly performance tuning specific)

Comment: can you provide the output of `sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep '^vm'` and `cat /proc/meminfo`. Preferably while the issue is occurring. If this is not possible, still post, there may be something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Are you running this on any virtual machine? I have a similar problem, although with another software.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are hitting resource limits.  Look at pam_limits.so and `/etc/security/limits.conf`.  These allow an administrator to set explicit limits on the resources a user can use so that one user can't hog all the system resources.  If Apache is hitting a limited specified by this, it will return an error like above even though there are plenty of resources other users can use.  There is also the `limit` or `ulimit` command in most shells, but I don't think that's the problem.